# Core consistent tick counter for ARM

Tags: multithreading, arm

I'm wondering if there's any counters on an ARM chip that can provide a tick-accurate count, but that is synced on all cores.   That is, if I have a process running on cpu1 and cpu2, and they both read the register, I would like to be able to compare the counters.   This would have to be from EL0, so unfortunately systick is out.   The PMU is per core, and I'm not aware of a method to sync their counters, so I unfortunately cannot use those either.   I also need very low latency, so a few register reads would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question --  It appears that the generic timer registers (`cntpct`, `cntvct`), etc are good for this purpose.  These registers still have a per-core enable bit to allow userspace access, but they all link to the same counter, and thus are in sync between the cores.